# converting fractions to decimals in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to input fractions such as 15/8 into google sheets and have them converted to decimal values.   Al the options I choose from format menu turn this into 15/08/22 or unrelated numbers eg 44660

Comment: u have to do : `=15/8` in the cell

Answer (score 0):

as answered by `@p._phidot_` you have to start with '=' sign when performing calculations in google-sheets or any spreadsheet app.

In your case: `=15/8`
otherwise it will convert it to date.